# Multi line buffered read in go

Tags: go

I am trying to read file in buffered manner because I have very large files. I want to apply some text replacement on a file. Suppose for each read I search for a word 'foo' and replace it with some other word 'bar'. If I read using buffer of some size 5MB then it may be the case foo will split into two reads may be one read 'fo' and another read 'o' then I will not be able to find that word. Is there a way so that I can use buffered read upto last newline or may be read multiple line in buffer
I did below. But It will not read upto next line or previous line

```
file, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()

byteSlice := make([]byte, 5*1024*1024) // read 5 MB
bufioreader := bufio.NewReaderSize(file, bufferSize)

for {
    n, err := bufioreader.Read(byteSlice)
    if n > 0 {
        fmt.Println(byteSlice[:n])
    } else if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the bufio reader, you shouldn't really work on aligning the input with buffer boundaries yourself. Use one of the high level read functions, such as `bufioreader.ReadString('\n'), which will read a line using the underlying buffer, and you won't have to deal with line delimiters yourself.

Comment: In my file Line are small may be 50 char, but file size could be 500 MB to 500 GB. So If I go line by line it is going to be read heavy(like billions of read overhead to syscall). Thats why I wanted to use buffer size of say 5MB or 500 MB based on my RAM

Comment: If you use a large buffer size, each read will fill the buffer, and then the reader will parse the lines from that buffer. It will not re-read the file for each line.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need bufio reader if you have your own buffer. With your code you have a useless copy of data from the buffer in bufio to the byteslice.

Regarding the split "foo" problem, the solution is to move the last 2 characters from the buffer to the front before the next read.

More precisely, if the word to replace has length *m*, the copy the *m-1* last letters of the buffer to the front of the buffer, fill the remain of the buffer and search for the word to replace in the buffer.

```golang
// assume we want to find word

file, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()

trailingLen := len(word)-1
dataLen := 5*1024*1024 + trailingLen
data := make([]byte, dataLen) // read 5 MB

for {
    n, err := file.Read(data[trailingLen:])
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        panic(err)
    }
    // search and replace word in data[:n]

    if n == dataLen {
        copy(data, data[dataLen-trailingLen:])
    }
}
```